# How to solve n sets of coupled equations in mathematica?

Tags: differential-equations

I have a lattice (1D) problem to solve, where I have $n$ particles, and each are coupled to neighbours via a harmonic potential.

```
D[x[n, t], t, t] == k * ((x[n + 1, t] - x[n, t]) - (x[n, t] - x[n - 1, t]))
```

End points are fixed and cannot move. Initially, we excite the particles in some normal mode, say.

How can I solve this set of equations using [`NDSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html)?

I can solve normal ODE or PDEs, but what I don't get is what should be done when there is a set of coupled equations. If `n` is large, it is impossible to write hundreds of coupled equations by hand.

Answer (score 5):

`NDSolve` can handle also equations in vector form; *Mathematica* can tell the dimension of the system from the initial conditions. The stiffness matrix can be easily obtained by `KirchhoffMatrix`. As employ random initial conditions for the positions and 0 for the velocities.

```
nparticles = 12;
k = 1.;
T = 10;
A = - k KirchhoffMatrix[
    UndirectedEdge @@@ Partition[Range[nparticles], 2, 1]];
sol = NDSolveValue[{
    X''[t] == A.X[t],
    X[0] == RandomReal[{-1, 1}, nparticles],
    X'[0] == ConstantArray[0., nparticles]
  }, 
  X, 
  {t, 0, T}];

Plot[sol[t], {t, 0, T}, PlotStyle -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You did not give enough information as what IC's are and so on. But here is something to get you started. I used random initial conditions for internal points.

Assuming there are 5 grid points (1D). So $x_0(t)$ and $x_n(t)$ are fixed point.

```
ClearAll[x, t]    
numberOfNodes = 5;
Array[x, numberOfNodes];
k = 3;
eqs = Table[
   If[n == 1, x[n]''[t] == 0, 
    If[n == numberOfNodes, x[n]''[t] == 0, 
     x[n]''[t] == 
      k ((x[n + 1][t] - x[n][t]) - (x[n][t] - x[n - 1][t]))]], {n, 1, 
    numberOfNodes}];
ic1 = {x[1][0] == 0, x[numberOfNodes][0] == 0, x[1]'[0] == 0, x[numberOfNodes]'[0] == 0};
ic2 = Table[{x[n][0] == RandomReal[], x[n]'[0] == RandomReal[]}, {n, 2, numberOfNodes - 1}];
sol = NDSolve[Flatten[{eqs, ic1, ic2}], Table[x[n][t], {n, 1, numberOfNodes}], {t, 0, 10}];
```

And now plot the solutions

```
Plot[Evaluate[{x[2][t], x[3][t], x[4][t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 10}, 
     PlotLegends -> {"x2(t)", "x3(t)", "x4(t)"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The ODE's are

```
eqs // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Change `numberOfNodes = 5;` to make 100's of them.

The end points do not move.

```
Plot[Evaluate[x[1][t] /. sol], {t, 0, 10}, PlotLegends -> {"x1(t)"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

As Nasser shows in his answer, one proper way to deal with this is through indexed variables, similar to what is done [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html).

```
With[{nn = 7, k = 1},
     ode = Table[D[x[n][t], t, t] == k ((x[n + 1][t] - x[n][t]) - (x[n][t] - x[n - 1][t])),
                 {n, nn}] /. {x[0][t] -> 0, x[nn + 1][t] -> 1};
     ic = Thread[Through[Array[x, nn][0]] == ArrayPad[Subdivide[nn + 1], -1]];
     icp = Thread[Through[Array[Derivative[1][x[#]] &, nn][0]] ==
                  PadRight[{}, nn, {-1, 1}/nn]];
     xf = NDSolveValue[Join[ode, ic, icp], Array[x, nn], {t, 0, 4}]];
```

To visualize the solution:

```
Animate[Graphics[Point[Join[{{0, 0}}, 
                            Transpose[PadRight[{Through[xf[t]]}, {2, Automatic}]],
                            {{1, 0}}]],
                 PlotRange -> {{-1/20, 1 + 1/120}, {-1/4, 1/4}}],
        {t, 0, 4}]
```

[image: 1D lattice harmonics]

---

Using indexed variables is the most general method. However, note that the functions are all connected linearly, and one can thus recast the system as a vector-valued ODE:

```
With[{nn = 7, k = 1},
     xfa = NDSolveValue[{xv''[t] ==
                         TranslationTransform[k UnitVector[nn, nn]][
                         SparseArray[{Band[{2, 1}] -> k, Band[{1, 1}] -> -2 k,
                                      Band[{1, 2}] -> k}, {nn, nn}].xv[t]], 
                         xv[0] == ArrayPad[Subdivide[nn + 1], -1], 
                         xv'[0] == PadRight[{}, nn, {-1, 1}/nn]}, xv, {t, 0, 4}]];
```

and then to get the same animation as the one above,

```
Animate[Graphics[Point[Join[{{0, 0}},
                            Transpose[PadRight[{xfa[t]}, {2, Automatic}]],
                            {{1, 0}}]], 
                 PlotRange -> {{-1/20, 1 + 1/120}, {-1/4, 1/4}}], {t, 0, 4}]
```